# Why does the modulo function in excel return the divisor?

Tags: excel-2010, validation

I have an Excel validation formula which worked fine in Office '03, '07, but is failing in 2010.  Did they change the definition of MOD recently?

In 03/07 the following returns zero:

```
=MOD(1, .05)
```

However in 2010 it returns `.05`.

As far as I can tell they haven't changed how remainders worked since I was in 3rd grade when I learned about them.  However, Microsoft may be taking certain liberties.

Comment: [Similar issue (floating point error) for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218961/why-fmod1-0-0-1-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally decided the best way to determine this was to cheat and do:

```
=(1/.05)-(floor(1/.05))
```

That gives me the zero I need.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... it does not return zero in Office 2007, but -0.000000000000000056 (just tested).

Maybe it's a floating point issue or the way Excel 2010 handles floating point changed.

Comment: Excel 2010 did fix a bug with the MOD function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Excel_MOD_function_error.It looks to me like they introduced another one, but you'd need to find the definition of the function for a non integer divisor.