# Division of 1 by 10 and saving it in a float variable gives me 0.000000, whereas I want it to be 0.1. How can it nbe possible

Tags: c++

I tried using fmod command but it gives me answer as 1.

fmod(1,10). this gives me 1.

I want an answer 0.1 when 1 is divided by 10.

Comment: You need to start looking up what things mean, rather than throwing random syntax at your computer and crossing your fingers.

Comment: And once you get it working but you do not get exactly `0.1` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `fmod` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) to see what the function *really* does.

Comment: check this one also :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218961/why-fmod1-0-0-1-1

Comment: using fmod might be wrong. then how can I get 0.1 instead of 0.000000

Comment: By using simple division? I.e `1.0 / 10.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a division actually

float fmod (float numer, float denom);
Returns the floating-point remainder of numer/denom.

In your case remainder is 1.